# GWT DialogBox never shows - help

Tags: java, gwt

I had wrote a test composite + entry point which are just to show my test DialogBox. 
The structure is...

- A) EntryPoint contains Composite
- B) Composite contains Button (in ScrollPanel) to show A class
- C) A class extends DialogBox

event listener code like a...

> button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {           public void
>   onClick(ClickEvent event) {
>                 DialogBox aDialog=new A();
>                 aDialog.center(); aDialog.show();           }       });

No doalogBox ever shown :( What am I doing wrong?

Any useful comment is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try adding `Window.alert("Handler called!");` in your Button's clickHandler to see the handler actually is being called. If you see a javascript alert dialog(handler is called) that means the problem is in your CustomDialogBox. Make sure you set the content of your dialog box by `setWidget(Widget w)` **BEFORE** you call `show()` to make it visible otherwise it won't show.

If no alert(handler is never called) that means the problem lies within your composite. It can be an issue of adding some of the elements directly to DOM without using widgets, it would break the gwt even mechanism(would explain why it works when you add button to root panel). Other than that, it is hard to tell without seeing some code.

Lastly I will post some working code in case you decide to work your way up from this to see where it fails. Here is a code that works :

First Extend DialogBox (dont forget to set its widget) :

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogBox {
    public CustomDialog() {
        setWidget(new Label("Hello!"));
    }
}
```

Then build a composite :

```
public CustomComposite() {
    Button b = new Button("Pop it up");
    b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            new CustomDialog().show();
        }
    });
    initWidget(b);
}
```

finally onModuleLoad :

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    CustomComposite c = new CustomComposite();
    RootPanel.get().add(c);
}
```

BTW : `center()` does center the pop up and then `show()`s, so you don't need to call both

Comment: Does the snippet work for you? I mean is it tested? Because I tried to extend the DialogBox but it never worked for me :( And will it be a modal one?

Comment: yes the code in my answer works. If you want it to be modal you just need to add setModal(true) in the constructor

Comment: OK. Thank you. I'll try it as soon as possible and report my results

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that you are not adding anything to the RootPanel, inwhichcase you are creating the DOM structure in memory but you are not attaching it to anything:

```
RootPanel.get().add(b);
```

Another reason is that you do not seem to call the .show method on the dialog:

```
new MyDialog().show();
```

There could be several reasons for the behavior you are describing, please post the complete example for a more targeted answer.

Comment: Another thing is I use show method but with DialogBox aDialog=new A(); aDialog.center(); aDialog.show(); is it correct?

Comment: And the button is in ScrollPanel widget... Can the ScrollPanel cause the problem?

Comment: Hmm... what b as RootPanel.get().add(b); means?

Comment: b would just be a randomly chosen name for a Widget. The point is you need to add your widgets to the root panel.

Comment: I have already added it but it doesn't help :( What else may cause the problem?

Comment: I have implemented EntryPoint as shown here http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox.html and added the dialog open button right to rootpane and only then it worked but the way helps with DialogBox itself :( I mean it doesn't allow to open an object which extends the DialogBox :( But why?

Comment: So it is still make my question unanswered :( Because I want to open a class which extends DialogBox :(

Answer (score 0):

I think I had similar problem before and what I did is calling the show() before center(). Would that help?

Comment: Emm... No, it didn't help . I tried to use extends DialogBox so maybe that is the problem?